# Cells with same values can be merged across rows or columns?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-ui-grid

I am planning to use Kendo UI Grid in AngularJS. I have a scenario with cells with same values can be merged across rows.

I want to implement row span in Kendo UI gird like attached picture?

Can anyone please help me on this.

Thank you so much in advance..[image: Kendo UI grid Row Span]

Comment: there is no direct method yet, can you checkout these links [link1](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/708865/How-to-merge-cells-in-Kendo-ui-Grid), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682573/how-to-merge-cells-in-kendo-ui-grid)

Comment: really..there is no way to do it by kendo ui grid?

Comment: I had the same problem with angular datatables, atleast kendo ui grid has a hot fix kind of thing, you need to add the javascript rowspan colspan code provided in the above links to a directive and try to make it work, if you are very determined to make it work.

Comment: Can you please guide me where I need to add this javascript code?

Comment: could you please tell me if you are working with angular 1? cause I have based my answer on angular 1

Answer (score 0):

I took the code from the [merging tables in javascript](http://www.arsnova.cc/articles/2013-08-26/merging-table-cells-jquery-javascript), [kendo UI rowspan](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/708865/How-to-merge-cells-in-Kendo-ui-Grid) and converted it into a working angular directive, I hope this will fix your issue.

**JSFiddle:** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/6kxxqjt1/)

**Code:**

```
myApp.directive('spanSupport', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
            var listOfColumns = scope.$eval(attrs.spanSupport) || [];
            console.log(listOfColumns);
                listOfColumns.forEach(function(column){
            angular.element('#' + attrs.id + '>.k-grid-content>table').each(function (index, item) {

                var dimension_col = 1;
                // First, scan first row of headers for the "Dimensions" column.
                angular.element('#' + attrs.id + '>.k-grid-header>.k-grid-header-wrap>table').find('th').each(function () {
                  if (angular.element(this).text() == column) {

                    // first_instance holds the first instance of identical td
                    var first_instance = null;

                    angular.element(item).find('tr').each(function () {

                      // find the td of the correct column (determined by the column)
                      var dimension_td = angular.element(this).find('td:nth-child(' + dimension_col + ')');
                      if (first_instance == null) {
                        first_instance = dimension_td;
                      } else if (dimension_td.text() == first_instance.text()) {
                        // if current td is identical to the previous
                        // then remove the current td
                        dimension_td.remove();
                        if(angular.element(this).find('td:nth-child(' + dimension_col + ')')[0] !== undefined){
                            var next_td = angular.element(this).find('td:nth-child(' + dimension_col + ')');
                            next_td.css("border-left-width", "1px");                          
                        } 
                        // increment the rowspan attribute of the first instance
                        first_instance.attr('rowspan', typeof first_instance.attr('rowspan') == "undefined" ? 2 : parseInt(first_instance.attr('rowspan')) + 1);
                      } else {
                        // this cell is different from the last
                        first_instance = dimension_td;
                      }
                    });
                    return;
                  }
                  dimension_col++;
                });
              });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Naren for the code..will this work in the grid with editable column and filters?

Comment: @BiswaranjanPradhan I have no idea, try it and adjust the code, I have provided the starting point for you